# Override default route if no parameter specified

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

Consider the following snippet:

```
  get '/hello/:name' do |n|
        "Hello #{n}!"
  end
```

How can I set a default parameters if name isn't specified? If I can set the default paramater to Tom will this also route the URL so /hello/ will automatically redirect to /hello/tom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do something like:

```
get '/hello/' do
  redirect '/hello/tom'
end
```

You could do 'hello/*' and access it through [`params[:splat]`](http://www.gittr.com/index.php/archive/sinatra-splat-routes/), if you just want one place for the logic. But you would still have to redirect to get to the /hello/tom url from /hello/.

Comment: So if I add that block, /hello/blah will still route ok?

Comment: yeah, they are distinct "end paths" as seen by the router :)